# Why can't i create a thread in while loop?

Tags: c++, multithreading, while-loop

I want to create a new thread inside a while loop but it makes the program instantly crash on start.
Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

void function1()
{

}

int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        thread thread(function1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You gotta paste some code, no one will be able help you with what you've posted here, a crash could be and be caused by anything.

Comment: You start by reading stackoverflow.com's [help], taking the [tour], learning [ask] questions, and what are the requirements for a [mre] if you want help with debugging. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your `std::thread` goes out of scope, its destructor is called.  The `std::thread` destructor calls `std::terminate()` if the thread is still active. You MUST `join()` or `detach()` the `std::thread` object before it is  destroyed.